# This.data from #each-iteration

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze, spacebars

I'm trying to access a value inside an {{#each in}}-iteration:

```
{{#each room in channels}}
  <form class="enterRoom">
    <button type="submit" class="roomJoin">
      <b>{{room.name}}</b>  
        <img src="{{room.roomBanner}}" alt=".">
           <input type="hidden" value="{{room.name}}" name="name">
         </button>            
          <div class="inRoom"> 
           {{#each name in room.inRoom}} 
              <a href="/c/{{name}}" target="_blank">{{name}}</a> 
           {{/each}}
          </div> 
  </form>
{{/each}}
```

Normally I would use `this.name`, for example, to get the name of it inside an event to use it further, like so

```
'submit .enterRoom'(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  const isClosed = this.name; // room.name example here

   }
```

But this doesn't work in this scenario. What I tried before was:

- `room.name`
- `this.room.name`

But those give the same error

```
chat.js:86 Uncaught ReferenceError: room is not defined
    at Object.submit .enterRoom (chat.js:86)
    at blaze.js?hash=51f4a3bdae106610ee48d8eff291f3628713d847:3818
    at Function.Template._withTemplateInstanceFunc (blaze.js?hash=51f4a3bdae106610ee48d8eff291f3628713d847:3769)
    at Blaze.View.<anonymous> (blaze.js?hash=51f4a3bdae106610ee48d8eff291f3628713d847:3817)
    at blaze.js?hash=51f4a3bdae106610ee48d8eff291f3628713d847:2617
    at Object.Blaze._withCurrentView (blaze.js?hash=51f4a3bdae106610ee48d8eff291f3628713d847:2271)
    at Blaze._DOMRange.<anonymous> (blaze.js?hash=51f4a3bdae106610ee48d8eff291f3628713d847:2616)
    at HTMLFormElement.<anonymous> (blaze.js?hash=51f4a3bdae106610ee48d8eff291f3628713d847:863)
    at HTMLDivElement.dispatch (modules.js?hash=8331598f8baf48556a442a64933e9b70b778274a:9685)
    at HTMLDivElement.elemData.handle (modules.js?hash=8331598f8baf48556a442a64933e9b70b778274a:9492)
```

Could someone explain to me how I could do it in this {{each in}}-setting properly?

Answer (score 0):

The error has nothing to do with the `each` iterations of your template. What you try is to get the form data within the `submit` event handle. However, there is no context bound to `this` or `room`.

In order to get the room value, you need to access the input value.

Blaze offers a fast way of doing so, by using the Template's builtin jQuery (using `templateInstance.$`), which automatically scopes to the Template root instead of the whole document:

```
'submit .enterRoom'(event, templateInstance) {
  event.preventDefault();
  const roomName = templateInstance.$(event.currentTarget).find('input[name="name"]').val();
  // ...
}
```

Comment: Okay, but in a normal {{each}}-iteration I'm able to target "this.data" even if there's not a input for this particular data. this.name is just an example in this case. These documents are room-documents and I'm actually looking for this.isClosed, a value that determines if a room is closed or not. And I don't think I can just put this boolean inside an input-value, for security reasons.